# Why is the request body empty when trying to call SOAP webservice with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

I have constructed a full soap envelope `soapEnvelopeXML` and I can see the call come through my TCP/IP Monitor, but the issue is that instead of calling the right method, the request URI comes in concatenated with the `soapEnvelopeXML` as if it is an option in the header. So i am not getting any result. I don't want to pass in the parameters as JSON objects. Any ideas on where i could be going wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/webservice/serviceName/",
    data: soapEnvelopeXML,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",       
    error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
        alert("Error processing your request: \n" + status + " : " + error);
    },
    success: function(response){
        var xml = $(response);
        alert(xml);
    }
});
```

---

I have tested the code on top to use POST instead of GET but I was getting an empty response and I see that an empty webservice call was being made. I didnt know that GET was illegal for SOAP requests. Does anyone know why the sent content is an empty call?

Comment: What is the value of the `soapEnvelopeXML` variable?

Comment: `soapEnvelopeXML` is standard soap envelope, something like  `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Header>CUSTOM HEADER</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>PARAMS</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Comment: In that case you should definately be using `POST` to send the data, as the answers below state.

Comment: Using POST seems to send out an empty web-service call.

Comment: Updated my answer to solve the second problem.  I repro'd your problem, and solved it on my box with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that SOAP should be POST?

http://www.coderanch.com/t/463869/Web-Services/java/SOAP-request-as-HTTP

> Q: How do I send a SOAP request as HTTP GET?
>
> A: You can't. SOAP always uses POST. Only REST uses GET (as well as various other HTTP methods, including POST).

### Update:

> Thanks for this, I was using GET because an empty web-service call was was made when I use POST. So any ideas as to why I make empty web-service calls when I use POST?

I am getting the same behavior on my local box **if I go to localhost**, but I got it working by doing this:

1. Make up a domain name
2. Stick it in the hosts file, pointing to `127.0.0.1`
3. Access the local webserver with that fake domain

Try this code, it is working for me:

```
var soapEnvelopeXML= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"> <soap:Header>CUSTOM HEADER</soap:Header> <soap:Body>PARAMS</soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://superblah.com/webservice/serviceName/",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    dataType: "xml",       
    data: soapEnvelopeXML,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "SOAPTarget",
        "http://superblah.com/webservice/serviceName/"
      );
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "SOAPAction",
        "http://superblah.com/webservice/serviceName/Something"
      );
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
        alert("Error processing your request: \n" + status + " : " + error);
    },
    success: function(response){
        var xml = $(response);
        alert(xml);
    }
});
```

I got this code from here:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests-With-jQuery.htm

Comment: Thanks for this, I was using GET because an empty web-service call was was made when I use POST. So any ideas as to why I make empty web-service calls when I use POST?

Comment: @abs: Solved it.  It won't work on localhost, only on a real domain.  Add a domain to your hosts file that points to `127.0.0.1`, and go to that domain instead.  Also see the code I added so you can set the `SOAPTarget` and `SOAPAction` correctly.

Comment: didn't know about jsfiddle, thanks. I am not making any cross-domain calls. Running the envelope on soapUI executes this properly so it's not an issue with the envelope. I have deployed and tested this but I get no result - similar issue.

Comment: Since you mentioned XSS and jsfiddle.net, I think you're replying to a slightly older version of my answer.  Check out the changes :)

Comment: thanks again for the detailed answer, I have mapped my localhost to some dummy domain name and was monitoring my port, i still see no change. The only change in the code is on the beforeSend, since i have the soap action in the envelope i didn't have to add it(not that i didn't try it :) ), still an empty call.

Comment: @abs: So just to be clear, you're also *accessing* that site using the dummy domain name, and you edited the AJAX call to use that dummy domain?  Cause if anything is localhost, it will still break.  I had the same problem you had, and pushing *everything* through the dummy domain fixed the problem on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is concatenated with the URL is that is what the `GET` method means.
Change this to POST and I suspect it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/webservice/serviceName/",
    data: soapEnvelopeXML,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",       
    error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
        alert("Error processing your request: \n" + status + " : " + error);
    },
    success: function(response){
        var xml = $(response);
        alert(xml);
    }
});
```